# Получение spring boot application context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Как можно получить доступ к UserRepository из CommandHandler, не передавая его по всему стеку вызовов? Пробовал использовать `@Autowrited ApplicationContext` в CommandHandler. В ApplicationContext просто падает null (как я понимаю, он еще не создан на момент инициализации CommandHandler). Если использовать конструктор с @Autowrited, то я не могу создать сам CommandHandler, не передав в него ApplicationContext. Замкнутый круг получается.

UserRepository.java

```
package ru.egas77.tgbot.finaltgspringboot.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import ru.egas77.tgbot.finaltgspringboot.models.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User getBytgid(long tgId);
}
```

CommandHandler.java

```
package ru.egas77.tgbot.finaltgspringboot.bot.handler;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import ru.egas77.tgbot.finaltgspringboot.anotations.Command;
import ru.egas77.tgbot.finaltgspringboot.bot.keyboard.Keyboard;
import ru.egas77.tgbot.finaltgspringboot.bot.state.StateManager;

@Service
public class CommandHandler {
    @Command(command = "/start")
    public SendMessage start(Update update, StateManager stateManager, Object... args) {
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        sendMessage.setText("Добро пожаловать");
        sendMessage.setReplyMarkup(Keyboard.startKeyboard);
        return sendMessage;
    }

    @Command(command = "/help")
    public SendMessage help(Update update, StateManager stateManager, Object... args) {
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        sendMessage.setText("Help");
        return sendMessage;
    }
}
```

Инициализация Command Handler

```
@Service
public class Handler extends HandlerBase {
    private final Bot bot;
    private static final CommandHandler commandHandler = new CommandHandler();
    private static final MessageHandler messageHandler = new MessageHandler();
    private static final Map<String, List<Method>> commandsHandlersMethods = new HashMap<>();
    private static final Map<State, Method> messagesHandlersMethods = new HashMap<>();
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы создаете объекты вручную, т.е. вызываете `new CommandHandler()`. В этом случае spring ничего об этих объектах не знает, и не внедряет в них зависимости, т.е. не обрабатывает `@Autowired`.

Нужно делать так:

```
@Service
public class Handler extends HandlerBase {
    private final Bot bot;
    @Autowired
    private CommandHandler commandHandler;
    @Autowired
    private MessageHandler messageHandler;
    ...
}

@Service
public class CommandHandler {
   @Autowired
   private UserRepository userRepository;
   ...
}
```

`static` их делать нельзя - спринг не умеет внедрять зависимости в static поля. С другой стороны spring создаст один экземпляр, так что все будет работать как вы ожидаете.

Cделать эти поля final конечно еще лучше. Для этого делайте внедрение через конструктор.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Это действительно работает так, как я и ожидал